# Set pointer content from a list of pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am getting quite confused with pointers right now so I hope someone can help me where I am making the error.

So I want to have a list of pointers to some structures, and one variable having pointers to all of them. This list should also later based on some conditions set and change those. So here just a minimal example:

```
typedef struct {
int a;

} path;

typedef struct {

path** all_paths;

} has_them;

int main(int argc, char** argv){

 path* eno = malloc(sizeof(path));
 path* second_path = malloc(sizeof(path));

 has_them* all = malloc(sizeof(has_them)); //this list should have all of my allocated path pointers
 all->all_paths = malloc(sizeof(path*)*10);
 all->all_paths[0] = eno; 
 all->all_paths[1] = second_path;

 printf("%p und %p\n", eno, second_path);
 printf("%p und %p\n", all->all_paths[0], all->all_paths[1]);

 all->all_paths[1] = NULL;

 printf("%p und %p\n", eno, second_path);
 printf("%p und %p\n", all->all_paths[0], all->all_paths[1]);

 return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

So my problem is, in my method I have only my all variable and I want using this one, to change my initial pointers (here eno and second_path), so set them to NULL for example.
But when I do it like i did it above, the initial pointer of second path is not null but stays the same...

Comment: Is `all->all_paths[1]_path = NULL;` a typo?  What's it supposed to be (it should give an error as is..)?

Comment: yes you are right, sorry about that. I just edited the post

Answer (score 0):

In this set-up, the **only** way to set `eno` and `second_path` to NULL is:

```
    eno = NULL;
    second_path = NULL;
```

No manipulations with `one` and its internal pointers can do that because `one` contains no information about *variables* `eno` and `second_path`. It only contains a copy of what `eno` and `second_path` also contain, namely, addresses of two malloc'd structs.  Fiddling with copies has no effect on originals.

Comment: so if i would set the variables of path to some value, then `all->all_paths[1] = NULL` would also set second_path to null??

Comment: @malajedala I don't understand what you are trying to do. Please update your question with more specific information.

Answer (score 0):

In fact to put the value of second_path to NULL by using the 'all' list of pointers, the element 'all->all_paths[1]' should be of type (path**) which points to the address of the pointer second_path. 
The variable 'all->all_paths' is like a table whose elements are the pointers to pointers of type 'path'. And to put the value of second_path to NULL, you can use the statement '*(all->second_path[1]) = NULL'

The field 'all_paths' of the structure 'has_them' should be of type 'path***' (three stars). And some changes should be made to the code.

Here is the code, it compiles and works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
int a;

} path;

typedef struct {

path*** all_paths;

} has_them;

int main(int argc, char** argv){

 path* eno = malloc(sizeof(path));
 path* second_path = malloc(sizeof(path));

 has_them* all = malloc(sizeof(has_them)); //this list should have all of my allocated path pointers
 all->all_paths = malloc(sizeof(path**)*10);
 all->all_paths[0] = (path**)&eno;
 all->all_paths[1] = (path**)&second_path;

 printf("%p und %p\n", eno, second_path);
 printf("%p und %p\n", *(all->all_paths[0]), *(all->all_paths[1]));

 //The second element of all->all_paths is nulled here
 *(all->all_paths[1]) = NULL;

 printf("%p und %p\n", eno, second_path);
 printf("%p und %p\n", *(all->all_paths[0]), *(all->all_paths[1]));

 return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Don't forget to free all the dynamically allocated variables when you don't need them anymore.

Comment: Omg you are right, this makes sense.. So can I remember that when I want to use other pointers to change my initial ones, I always need one  pointer dimension more?